# Magento 2 REST API delete all products

Tags: product, rest-api

I want to delete all product using Rest API in Magento 2.

Comment: magento2 does not have any api to delete products in mass action.Only have API  for delete product one by one using id

Comment: @AmitBera that's wrong. you can use bulk-actions. you still have to know the IDs, but you don't need a request for each product

Comment: Which api point do that.Please give me API point

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all products by iterating them and calling the REST DELETE command on `/V1/products/:sku`.

Here is the specific endpoint:
https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.1-admin/tag/productssku#operation/catalogProductRepositoryV1DeleteByIdDelete

A list of endpoints can be found here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html

Integrations don't have this ability by default though. You have to login and get an access token.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all products in Magento 2 using the REST API, follow these steps:

1. Obtain an Access Token:

   - Log in to your Magento 2 Admin Panel.
   - Go to System > Extensions > Integration.
   - Click "Add New Integration" and fill in the required details.
   - Under API, select "All" for the resource access.
   - Save the integration and note down the Access Token generated.
2. Send DELETE Request:

   - You can use any REST API client or tools like cURL or Postman.
   - Make a DELETE request to the following endpoint:
     http://your-magento-site.com/rest/V1/products
   - Include the necessary headers in your request:

     - Authorization: Bearer [Access Token]
     - Content-Type: application/json
3. Confirm Deletion:

   - The API will respond with a status code indicating the success of the request.
   - Verify that the response code is 204 (No Content), which indicates that the products have been deleted successfully.

Please note:

- Make sure to have a backup and necessary permissions before performing the deletion operation.
- Replace "http://your-magento-site.com" with your actual Magento 2 installation URL.
- Replace [Access Token] with the Access Token obtained in step 1.

Take caution when performing bulk deletion operations and test it in a development/staging environment before production.